# KL Divergence - Convolution of distributions

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory

Assume $P_1,P_2,P_3$ different to each other pmfs. We would like to find an upper bound for $D_{\text{KL}}(P_1\ast P_3||P_2 \ast P_3)$, where $D_{KL}$ is the [Kullback-Leibler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) divergence and $*$ is convolution. By using the log sum inequality we can get $D_{\text{KL}}(P_1\ast P_3||P_2 \ast P_3) \leq D_{\text{KL}}(P_1||P_2 )$. Is there any way to get a tighter bound?

Comment: Where does this question come from?

Comment: it looks like it is a strict inequality ($P_1 \neq P_2 $), however, I was wondering if $P_3$ could participate to the right part.

Comment: Since this is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2326512/kl-divergence-convolution-of-distributions you should at least mention that you are asking in more than one place, to prevent unnecessary duplication of effort.  That is a basic curtesy to people who are working for free.

Comment: sorry I didn't know that

Comment: Isn't this essentially the data processing inequality?

Comment: Yes it is, I am looking for specific upper bounds of the ratio of the KL divergences. Notice that is not always true for $f$ divergences and continuous random variables. Here are 2 papers related to this topic: 
 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.3575.pdf    https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.06025.pdf.

Comment: Cauchy, did you find the answer to this question? I'm working on a proof whose most important step needs a tighter inequality.

Comment: @SudeepRaja, not really.  For dependent random variables the problem seems to be hard

Comment: @Cauchy I have a similar question, but in my case everything is independent. Do you know an answer for the independent case?